# Make short hash from long string

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, hash, cryptojs

I have a very long string and I need a unique ID to cache it.
The id doesn't need to be reversed however equal strings need to return the equal id.

For example:

- this-is-a-very-long-string -> SFG2527G
- this-is-something-else -> JSNTFK2783
- this-is-a-very-long-string -> SFG2527G

I don't need to reverse the hash.

What's the best way to achieve this with Javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API

Comment: I don't understand the question. What you describe is basically what a hash does, so since you already tagged your question with `cryptojs`, just choose a hashing algorithm (e.g. SHA-1), and use that. Just keep in mind: the shorter your hash values, the higher the risk of collisions.

Comment: Yes this seems to work:
`const long_string = 'hey there'`
`const hash = require('crypto').createHash('sha256').update(long_string, 'utf8').digest('hex');`

Comment: I thought that a hash would be always longer than the string. However it's not the case. I tried with a very long string and it's still reasonably short.

Comment: Most hash algorithms generate hashes of a fixed length. For SHA-256, it's 256 bits, so 64 hex characters.

Comment: Great. Feel free to post it in the answer & I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shorter the hash, the higher the chances of collision.

However, in the *Java* world, there is a string `hashCode` helper that returns a "*not so unique*" integer out of a string, and it's the smallest way to map a string as ID, but **it doesn't guarantee uniqueness** and **it suffers collisions**.

Accordingly, I strongly discourage you to use this in the wild, but for answer sake, here how you can play around with such hash:

```
function hashCode(s) {
  for (var h = 0, i = 0; i < s.length; h &= h)
    h = 31 * h + s.charCodeAt(i++);
  return h;
}
```

On the other hand, *sha256* is a one way hashing that "*doesn't suffer collisions*" (it does, but much less than MD5, SHA1, or the `hashCode` up there), so while the result is a longer unique id, it's *kinda* granted to always work as expected, and it's [explained in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest#examples).

P.S. NodeJS 15+ has a `crypto.webcrypto` namespace that is identical to the Web one, so you can use the same code in browsers and server.

Comment: it's in quotes, because it **does** suffer collision, like every one-way hashing that produces a finite set of chars, but it's extremely rare in the real world, and considered much more robust than MD5 or SHA1, but it has better performance than SHA-512, which also suffers collisions. They all do. Compared to the *Java* hash, which suffers more collisions than anything else, SHA-256 is a safe enough, and fast, bet.

Comment: Putting it in double quotes means that you should take it with a pinch of salt. Yes, collisions do occur but are extremely unlikely. 2^256 is approximately 1.158 * 10^77. That's a lot of possible values and can therefore hash a lot of possible inputs without collisions.

Comment: P.S. I've edited the answer so we can move forward with our day.